# How to calculate the volume of the $4$-dimensional closed sphere?

Tags: calculus, integration, volume

I started by integration of 3D formula for sphere volume. Not good or?
The closed sphere has a centre $(0,0,0,0)$ and a radius $a > 0$ in the $4$-dimensional space: $x^2 + y^2 + z^2 + w^2 \le a^2$.

Comment: @NormalHuman: Maybe, but that question is nonsensical since its author confuses balls with spheres and also has a dimensional problem.

Comment: @AlexM. So does the author here. :)

Comment: The $n$-sphere $S^n = \{x\in \mathbb{R}^{n+1}:\,x_0^2 + \cdots + x_n^2 = 1\}$ is the boundary of the $(n+1)$-ball $B^{n+1} = \{x\in \mathbb{R}^{n+1}:\, x_0^2 + \cdots + x_n^2 \leq 1\}$. What you describe is (up to a constant factor) $B^3$, not $S^4$. In this context, "closed" usually means "compact without boundary."

Comment: @anomaly: I think that the OP wants to compute the volume of the (topologically closed) $4$-ball.

Comment: @AlexM. : Too late for me to edit my comment, but you're completely right.